# How to give a prefix to all columns of a JOINed table in Zend Framework 2?

Tags: mysql, zend-framework2, zend-db, zend-db-select

In my current Zend Framework 2 project I have a data schema like this:

```
car
    id
    type -> ENUM('Tesla', 'AstonMartin', 'Bmw')
    common_attribute

car_tesla
    car_id
    specific_attribute_a
    specific_attribute_b
    specific_attribute_c

car_aston_martin
    car_id
    specific_attribute_a
    specific_attribute_b
    specific_attribute_d

car_bmw
    car_id
    specific_attribute_b
    specific_attribute_d
    specific_attribute_e
```

On the application level it's an inheritance, where `Car` is an abstract super-class and `CarFoo`, `CarBar`, and `CarBuz` its sub-classes.

I want to retrieve the entire data and build in the next step concrete `Car` objects.

To make the building of objects from the selected data easier, I'm using prefixes:

```
    $sql = new Sql($this->dbAdapter);
    $select = $sql->select('car')->columns('car_id' => 'id' ...);
    $select->join('car_tesla', 'car_tesla.car_id = car.id', [
        'car_tesla_specific_attribute_a' => 'specific_attribute_a',
        ...
        'car_tesla_specific_attribute_c' => 'specific_attribute_c'
    ]);
    $select->join('car_aston_martin', 'car_aston_martin.car_id = car.id', [
        'car_aston_martin_specific_attribute_a' => 'specific_attribute_a',
        ...
        'car_aston_martin_specific_attribute_d' => 'specific_attribute_d'
    ]);
    ...
```

It's a lot duplicated code...

**How to build the statement with `Zend\Db` the way, that every column gets a prefix (e.g. the name of its table) automatically / defined at one place?**

<sup>[Here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/137801/how-to-give-a-prefix-to-all-columns-of-a-joined-table-in-mysql) I'm trying to resolve the problem on the database level.</sup>

Comment: You might consider using a car attributes table rather than a table for each individual car make.  Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model for more info.